# Entity Framework: Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm getting this error while updating the model I'm sharing my code, please tell me the best solution for this.

Ticket Detail Class:

```csharp
public class TicketDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int TicketDetailId { get; set; }
    public int GenericOrderId { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? CustomerPrice { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

OrderDetailClass:

```csharp
public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
    public int GenericOrderId { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Order Class:

```csharp
public class Order : GenericOrder
{
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Ticket Class

```csharp
public class Ticket : GenericOrder
{
    public virtual ICollection<TicketDetail> TicketDetails { get; set; }
}
```

GenericOrderClass:

```csharp
public abstract class GenericOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int GenericOrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProcessId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the controller class code

```csharp
TryUpdateModel(order);
TryUpdateModel(ticket);

try
{
    order.Date = DateTime.Now;
    ticket.Date = DateTime.Now;
    order.ProcessId = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(12, 6);
    ticket.ProcessId = order.ProcessId;

    //Add the Order
    storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
    storeDB.Tickets.Add(ticket);

    //Process the order
    cart.CreateOrder(order);
    cart.CreateTicket(ticket);

    // Save all changes
    storeDB.SaveChanges();

    //return RedirectToAction("Complete",
    //    new { id = order.QuoteOrderId });
    TempData["OrderSuccess"] = "Your order has been submitted successfully with the Process ID " + order.ProcessId;
    TempData["OrderId"] = order.GenericOrderId;
    TempData["Email"] = order.Email;

    return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Invalid - redisplay with errors
    ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
    return View(order);
}
```

I have searched internet but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: What does `cart.CreateOrder` do?

Comment: @GertArnold it is inserting order details into db

Answer (score 0):

Try saving Order and Ticket and after they are saved add Details to them.